# C++ vector memory errors for a start/stop sorting algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, vector, simulation

I have two problems, first the below code is quitting randomly because of a memory or uninitialized place error, I just can't see it. second, I'm not sure that the algorithm is correct. (The algorithm is suppose to simulate the [Hanbury Brown Twiss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect) photonics experiment for anyone who cares)

The vectors are made up of linearly increasing time stamps, where the stop signal is delayed by 180 seconds, if the i_th start signal is less than the i_th stop signal, the timer starts, ignoring all start signals until the timer meets a stop signal, and vica versa, if the timer is stopped, all stops should be ignored until a start is registered.
The code should then [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) the time difference between these start/stops.

-If there is a name for this kind of sort please post it below.

The below code takes these filled vectors and tries to simulate this process. but I cant figure out what wrong with the memory issues before I get back to fixing the algorithm.

this is the code I have that doesn't work all the time, it works for start/stop vectors smaller than 10,000 double, but I need it to iterate through up to 100,000 doubles.

```
   while( starts.size() > 5 && stops.size() > 5 ){
      if( start.at(0) >= stop.at(0) ){
         thisStart = starts.at(0);
      }
      j=0;
      while( stops.at(j) <= starts.at(0) ){
         j++;
      }
      stops.erase(stops.begin(), stops.begin() + j + 1 );
      thisStop = stops.at(0);
      j=0;
      while( starts.at(j) <= thisStop){
         j++;
      }
      starts.erase(starts.begin(), starts.begin() + j+1 );
      bucketSort(thisStop - thisStart, bins, &counts);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while( stops.at(j) <= starts.at(0) ){
         j++;
      }
```

This loop will go out of bounds if it doesn't find an element in `stops` that's less than or equal than `starts[0]`. An `out_of_range` exception will be thrown, that's what `at()` is supposed to do. I don't know if that's your problem since you didn't specify exactly what kind of error you're getting, but it's certainly something to look for.

You'd might want to have a condition like this:

```
while (j < stops.size() && stops[j] <= starts[0]) { ... }
```